# Error al instalar linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Teno un pc de escritorio y necesito instalar linux urgente, lo booteo bien sin problemas pero sale un error cuando corro el pendrive, ya intente con ubuntu, kutunbu, ubutntu mate

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi pc 
i5-9400F
asus prime h310 r2.0 
gpu gtx 1650
16 gb de ram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El mensaje en pantalla es claro, dice que no encontró ningún Sistema Operativo, es probable que no se copió bien el SO al pendrive.

Yo uso el programa [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) para crear mi pendrive booteable con Ubuntu y nunca tuve problemas.

También es probable que el pendrive tenga problemas de lectura/escritura. Sería bueno probar también con otros pendrives y ver si el problema persiste.

Comment: Exactamente es como dice el compañero, te recomiendo primero formatear el pendrive.

Comment: lo formatie varias veces pero rufus me elimino la particion y con eso se arreglo, muchas gracias!